# Navigating Django Apps with home page buttons and page buttons

Tags: python, django

Quick question and I don't know why this isn't easier to find but how do I switch between the home page index to another app's index page. My current setup:

```
kkquit/index.html - homepage
pack/index.html - page I want to link
```

What is the proper way to label a button to go from my index home page to another apps index page?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an app_name in the `urls.py` for both apps... For example:

Within the `kkquit` app `urls.py` file you'll have...

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'kkquit'  # declaring the app_name here

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='home'),
]
```

And within the `pack` app `urls.py` file you'll have...

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'pack'  # declaring the app_name here

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='home'),
]
```

Now in your project's folder... You'll have these be included within your project's `urls.py` file like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('kkquit.urls', namespace="kkquit")),  # Adding the value of this app app_name from the url.py kkquit as the namespace
    path('pack/', include('pack.urls', namespace="pack")),  # Adding the value of this app app_name from the url.py pack as the namespace
]
```

Now with that been set up you can navigate between the two apps from your front end.

You have two buttons or nav links, for example:

```
<a href="{% url 'kkquit:home' %}">kkquit index page</a>

<a href="{% url 'pack:home' %}">pack index page</a>
```

Comment: Very useful. One addition: while using this method, you also have to specify the namespace of the app for each view. For instance, if you have a view named `buy` under the app `pack`, then you specify the namespace and view name with `{% url 'pack:buy' %}